# Display Related List as pdf

Tags: visualforce

I have a custom object called Credits that is related to Contacts via lookup relationsihp.

I added a button in the Contact page that displays a pdf of the credits for that specific contact.

I know the apex to display a page as pdf but unsure how I can display Credits only for that contact?  Do I need a controller?  How do I pass the value of the contact ID to the page?

```
<apex:page standardController="Credits__c" showHeader="false" renderAs="pdf"> 
<apex:pageBlock title="Credits">
<table>
<tr>
<td width="15%"><apex:outputLabel value="Course Number: " for="coursenumber" /></td>
<td width="35%"><apex:outputField id="coursenumber" value="    {!RITT_Credits__c.Course_Number__c}"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: <apex:page standardController="Credits__c" showHeader="false" renderAs="pdf">
<apex:pageBlock title="Credits">
   
      <table>
         <tr>
             <td width="15%"><apex:outputLabel value="Course Number: " for="coursenumber" /></td>
              <td width="35%"><apex:outputField id="coursenumber" value="{!RITT_Credits__c.Course_Number__c}"/></td>       
         </tr>
         
       </table>      
     
    </apex:pageBlock>
    
</apex:page>

Answer (score 2):

The standard controller (the one you have now) should work fine for your purposes here. You'd pass the contact ID to the page like this:

```
https://ssl.salesforce.com/apex/YourVFPageName?id=YourID
```

There's a number of ways you could display just the Credits, but apex:relatedList might be the simplest. Apex:pageBlockTable is another possibility.  For more control over the appearance, use apex:datatable.

Comment: Your answer is technically correct but I don't think it'll help much ;) Consider posting some links to documentation like https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_relatedList.htm or maybe even showing a small sample in your answer? I suspect Jen doesn't know how to iterate over `Contact.Credits__r` relationship (assuming that's the name) so the raw names of tags won't help much